# Style in external stylesheet not same as using style=

Tags: css

I've got a DIV element styled as follows:

```
<div style='float: left; width: 100px; position: relative; top: +5px;'>
 This is some text
</div>
```

When I move the style into an external stylesheet the "top: +5px;" bit isn't being applied to the text but the rest of the style is:

```
div.textthumb {
  float: left; width: 100px; position: relative; top: +5px;
}

...

<div class='textthumb'>
 This is some text
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: remove the `+` - that isn't valid css

Comment: As you're using position:relative, you can simply write top:5px, without '+'. Never used it and don't know if it is important ;p

Answer (score 0):

The '+' in your style is unnecessary, only sign required if you are looking for a negative margin:

```
div.textthumb {
  float:left; width:100px; position:relative; top:5px;
}
```

If that does not fix your issue, then you may need to look for another style that you have specified that is overriding this.  Using the developer bar in chrome or firebug will help you here.

Comment: The `+` sign is redundant, but allowed, and it does not affect the issue.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Paddy's answer, you could use the CSS property **!important** to force it on the element:

```
div.textthumb {
   float: left;
   width: 100px;
   position: relative;
   top: 5px !important;
}
```